# How do I check if a windows phone has GPS active?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a GPS application and during startup I want to check if the GPS is active - if not I want to enable it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your application cannot control the status of the GPS.

You can, however, start and stop data acquisition.

Look into System.Device.Location